# bufio.NewScanner.Scan hangs the program

Tags: go

I have the following code snippet

```
package main
import (
  "os/exec"
  "bufio"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("terraform", "init")
  cmd.Dir = ""
  stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
  stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
  stdoutScanner.Scan()
  fmt.Println("End of main")
}
```

stdoutScanner.Scan() hangs forever without any outputs

I am in a VPC with proxy.

Is there any possible reason why this happens ?

Comment: Try to give simple example, remove unnecessary things while asking questions like testing, command and other external packages.

Comment: @nilsocket  thanks for the comment. I have reedited the question :)

Comment: @MartinTournoij  Scan() function, outputs nothing. I try to make a MCV example

Comment: `package main

import (
 "bufio"
 "fmt"
 "log"
 "os"
 "os/exec"
)

func main() {
 cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-l", "-h")
 cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
 stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
 b := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
 err := cmd.Start()
 if err != nil {
  log.Println(err)
 }
 for b.Scan() {
  fmt.Println(b.Text())
 }
}
`You didn't start the command, you should start the command once all parameters were set. The above example just work's fine.

Comment: Also `Scanner.Scan()` isn't *supposed* to output anything. It *returns* a value (which you're discarding), it prints nothing.

Comment: @nilsocket That looks like an answer. It should probably be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comments were added where ever required.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    //args should be specified as you provide them in terminal
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-l", "-h")
    //set all required parameters
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    b := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    //start the command
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    //see if you have something, until EOF
    //b.Scan() blocks until you get some input, or EOF
    //It's something like streaming input.
    for b.Scan() {
        //print the input
        fmt.Println(b.Text())
    }
}
```